# JWPlayer is not working when loaded as ajax content in fancybox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, fancybox, jwplayer6

I'm using fancybox to load content via AJAX. In my main view, clicking a button will get a partial view from the server & display it in fancybox:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    src: url,
    type: 'ajax'});
```

The partial view contains JWPlayer in addition to other content. The JWPlayer setup is called as part of the partial view scripts, it's then loaded but the play button doesn't work. I'm using fancyBox3 & jwplayer6

If anyone can provide guidance I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you would need to use a callback to initialize player.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Where should the callback you're suggesting be used?

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api